# Different sh interpretation between Solaris and RHEL of a null variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a problem with the code below:
-RHEL :

```
Linux 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 13 00:51:26 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ sh
sh-4.1$ FAX=""
sh-4.1$ if [ "$FAX" -eq "" ]; then FAX="+390000000";fi;echo $FAX
sh: [: : integer expression expected
sh-4.1$ which sh
/bin/sh
sh-4.1$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

-Solaris:

```
SunOS 5.10 Generic_150401-13 i86pc i386 i86pc
$ sh
$ FAX=""
$ if [ "$FAX" -eq "" ]; then FAX="+390000000";fi;echo $FAX
+390000000
$ which sh
/usr/bin/sh
```

the right code should be:
`if [ "$FAX" == "" ]; then FAX="+390000000";fi;echo $FAX`

the previous developers have released a lot of scripts with the error code above under Solaris and now I need to migrate the system to RHEL.

Is it possible to change some RHEL parameters or RHEL sh version to solve this problem ?

Thanks a lot.
Ruggiero

Comment: What is the shell Solaris is running? You probably can get that for Linux also. bash uses -eq for integers only

Comment: Hi Sami, at the top of the Solaris script I found: "#!/bin/sh". I know that "-eq" is used only for integers, but it works under Solaris and not in RHEL. How can I install the sh (Solaris) in RHEL ?

Comment: First you have to know which shell it is. sh doesn't say much since usually it's a symlink to the actual shell.

Comment: The Solaris 10 /usr/bin/sh is very old and not POSIX compliant. Its builtin test and [ commands treat any unparseable number (such as `""` or `"foo"`) as 0 in numeric comparisons. It may be difficult to find an equally nonconcompliant shell on RHEL. Even old shells like `ash` and `dash` flag `""` as an Illegal Number. Is it possible for you to fix the incorrect code?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for clarifying this!